# Testing formik onSubmit funtion using jest does not work

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, formik

How to test formik onsubmit fucntion?

My onSubmit handler (mockFunction) is executed after a little delay. If I put a console.log or expect statement immediately after **form.props().onSubmit()**, the test fails because the handler is not yet called.

This is my form component

```
const CreateNavItemFormInner = ({
  onSubmitNavItem,
}) => (
<Formik
    onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
      console.log('onSubmit called, calling mock function')
      onSubmitNavItem(values) 
    }}
// other code
```

Here is my test

```
it('calls onSubmitNavItem on form submission', ()=> {
    const mockFunction = jest.fn(v => {
      console.log('inside mock function', v)
      // done()
    })

const props = {
  onSubmitNavItem: mockFunction,
  validate: jest.fn(values => {
    console.log('validating ', values)
    return {}
  }),
}
    const wrapper = mount( <CreateNavItemFormInner {...props} /> )
    const form = wrapper.find('form').first()
    form.props().onSubmit()

    console.log('after onSubmit ==> ')
    // mockFunction.mock.calls.length returns 0
    // expect(mockFunction.mock.calls.length).toBe(1) , this fails
    // expect(mockFunction).toHaveBeenCalled(), this fails too
  })
```

Output

```
console.log src/components/NavigationSettings/CreateNavItemForm/__tests__/CreateNavItemForm.test.js:26
    validating  { url: '', title: '' }

  console.log src/components/NavigationSettings/CreateNavItemForm/__tests__/CreateNavItemForm.test.js:53
    after onSubmit ==>

  console.log src/components/NavigationSettings/CreateNavItemForm/CreateNavItemFormInner.js:26
    onSubmit called, calling mock function

  console.log src/components/NavigationSettings/CreateNavItemForm/__tests__/CreateNavItemForm.test.js:18
    inside mock function { url: '', title: '' }
```

I have made my test pass using first example in this link.
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous

But could someone please explain to me why there is a delay? Is formik's onSubmit function asynchronous?

Comment: Did u solve it @Nida Munir?

Comment: Formik runs validation asynchronously before calling onSubmit, which is why you see that delay. Making your test case asynchronous either with the done callback or with async/await will probably solve the problem.